# While scrolling panel on my html page , content behind the panel also scrolls

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used panel to display some specific info to users in my app. panel opens on click of button which is part of navigation bar.navigation bar is fixed in my html. Now when i open panel and scroll, content inside the panel scrolls which is expected but when i scroll the page behind the panel then that page also scrolls which i do not want. I tried with one trick of fixing the div behind the panel  when panel is clicked but page looks odd after that.
Anyone please help.

Comment: please post your code for someone to see the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On click of button to open the navmenu, apply style overflow hidden to the body. This will prevent the content scrolling.

Comment: I am using single html having multiple divs for different screens. All are inside body tag, once panel open in its div it has a z-index greater than other divs so it stand out on screen. When i apply overflow hidden to body , that gets applied to panel also because its part of body and content inside panel does not scroll.